# importing org.eclipse.core packages for Eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I'm trying to create a plug-in to mimic the Eclipse open resource dialog (CTRL+SHIFT+R).  I've learned how to create a FilteredItemsSelectionDialog by following the [example](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/dialogs_FilteredItemsSelectionDialog.htm).  But the missing piece is how to fill the dialog with the workspace resources.  I found [OpenResourceHandler](http://devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.ui.ide/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/ide/handlers/OpenResourceHandler.java.shtml) and am trying to duplicate this functionality in my plug-in, so I can step through and see how it works.  So I copy the source and rename it to avoid colliding with the real one.  The problem is that I cannot import these classes:

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IContainer;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
```

I tried editing my Manifest but it will not let me import org.eclipse.core (although I can import org.eclipse.core.runtime).  So, where do I find these classes and how can import them?  And, more importantly, in general how would I find the bundle a given class exists in and import it?

Comment: Hi @harschware, I want to develop a plugin that does a similar thing. Is the project that spawned this question open source (so I could learn from your solution)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to import `org.eclipse.core.resources`.

In general, you can open the "Plug-ins" view (Window -> Show View -> Other -> Plug-in Development -> Plug-ins).  Then, select interesting plug-ins and right click -> Add to Java Search.  Then you can use Open Type (Ctrl + Shift + T) to open the class.

Also, in the package explorer, change the Filters to not exclude "External plug-in libraries project".  "Link with Editor" can then show you what bundle contains the class you just opened.