# Importing org.eclipse.core.resources with Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Version: Indigo Service Release 2).

For my project, I wrote the code: `IResource resource= new IResource()`. I added the import statement `import org.eclipse.core.resources.`  I downloaded the `org.eclipse.core.resources-3.7.101.v20120125-1505.jar` and put it on my project build path and restarted eclipse, but the import cannot be resolved. I tried other version `org.eclipse.core.resources-3.8.100.v20130521-2026.jar`, but still did not work.  I tried the solution suggested in [importing org.eclipse.core packages for Eclipse plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086859/importing-org-eclipse-core-packages-for-eclipse-plug-in),
but did not help.

What do I need to do in order to get `import org.eclipse.core.resources` and IResource class to work for me? You help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually developing an Eclipse plug-in? This code can only be used in a plug-in and even then you can't create a resource like that.

Comment: No I am not developing a plugin. I was trying to use the IResource class in order to dynamically  "Refresh" my project (or a folder within) after creating a java class dynamically. I am developing a project in which I read text code files, instrument the code and then create a java class dynamically and run it. The problem I am facing is that my dynamically created class would not be recognized when I use the following code unless I refresh my project "manually":  try {
    testClass= Class.forName(className);
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: You can't do this. The resources plugin will only work in a proper Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Ok. Is there another way to solve my problem?  I need to "refresh" a folder or the whole project dynamically or any other way to avoid getting the "ClassNotFoundException" when I call Class.forName(calssName) method.

Comment: There is a 'Refresh using native hooks or polling' option in the Preferences in 'General > Workspace' to get Eclipse to pick up changes automatically. Or write a proper Eclipse plugin to do the code gen so you can use the correct refresh API.

Answer (score 1):

`import org.eclipse.core.resources` would import a *class* named org.eclipse.core.resources, not the classes in that package. You would need to `import org.eclipse.core.resources.*`.

Even so, the plug-ins that ship as part of an Eclipse download expect to run within an Eclipse Runtime. With rare exceptions, can't just use them in a Java Application, so just adding them to your Java Build Path manually isn't constructive.